# Can you suggest some source(s) from where one can practice problems on Network routing games (Game Theory)?

Tags: game-theory, network-flow, algorithmic-game-theory

I want to practice problems on topics like selfish routing games, network formation games.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by practice problems? Do you mean instances of these games? Or do you mean theoretical questions?